# Sum of xor of digits of all numbers from 1 to N when N is very large

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given 1 and N , we need to find the sum of XOR values of digits of all numbers from 1 to N,
For example  for N  ,  we need to compute function F

```
F(k){
    ans =0;
    while(k>0){
      ans= ans^(k%10);
      k/=10;
   }
   return ans;
}
```

for  K in [1,N].

is there a efficient way to do say .
As far as i can think we should count the no of times a value V will resultant XOR using DP , but i cant think of way to implement it.

Please Give some Idea upon it.

Example : F (37) = 3 ^ 7 = 4

Note : N can be as large as 10^18

Comment: Are you sure it is xor of decimal digits, not xor of binary digits?

Comment: i have added an example

Comment: All you really need to know is whether the number of occurrences of each digit (0..9) for the range 1..N is odd or even.

Comment: You just have to count how many times every digit repeats for that set of numbers. Exclude digits with even counts, xor digits with odd counts

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach takes `O(N*log10(N))` time, by doing a simple optimization you could get `O(N)` runtime. The idea is:

XOR of all the digits of a k digit number = XOR of first (k - 1) digits ^ last digit.

Obviously, you could find the first k - 1 digits by dividing the number by 10, so the relationship becomes:

`F(i) = F(i / 10) ^ (i % 10)`

Code:

```
result = 0
for i = 1:N
  dp[i] = dp[i/10] ^ i%10
  result += dp[i]
```

Comment: but N can be as large as 10^18

Comment: How is that different from the example in the question?

Comment: @user269985 Oh, then it won't work then due to memory constraints :(

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername It is taking O(1) operation to calculate F(i) for a single number. In the example, O(log10(i)) operations are needed to do the same.

Comment: You're confusing digits with numbers here. N is the boundary on the number

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Could you please clarify a little bit? What I meant is my approach will take, say O(10^8) operations for 10^8 numbers (O(1) for each of the numbers between 1 to 10^8). In the example, calculating F(i) for a single number could take 1 to 8 operations, depending on how many digits are in that number. So in total it will take ~O(8*10^8) operations for 10^8 numbers.

Comment: In OP's example for `k` it also takes log(number of decimal digits). Also, it's not clear what the `dp` represents in your answer. It should correspond to F(), but the syntax implies an array.

Answer (score 0):

- Let's compute a slightly different thing: how many numbers from 1 to N have the xor of its digits equal to `X` for all `X from 0 to 15`.
- Once we know it, the answer to your problem is just the sum of `count[X] * X` for all valid `X`'s.
- How can we count it efficiently? We'll use a standard **digit-by-digit dynamic programming**.
- We can treat all numbers as strings. If we pad them with zeros so that their length is equal to the number of digits in `N`, we can compare them lexicographically.
- The state of the dynamic programming is: `(prefixLength, curXor, isSmaller)` - the number of ways to place the first `prefixLength` most significant digits in such a way that their xor is `curXor`. `isSmaller` is true if this prefix is smaller than the prefix of `N`. Otherwise, the prefix is equal to that of `N`.
- The transition is placing one more digit. The `curXor` changes trivially. The `prefixLength` increases by one. If `isSmaller` is true, we can place any digit and go on. Otherwise, we can't put a larger digit than the digit at this position in `N`. If we put the same one, `isSmaller` stays false. Otherwise, it becomes true.
- Let `L` be the number of digits in `N`. Than there're exactly `f(L, X, 0) + f(L, X, 1)` numbers that have the xor of their digits equal to `X` in the `[1, N]` range.
- We're done! The number of states is roughly 16 * L * 2 and the number of transitions is around 16 * L * 2 * 10. As `L = O(log N)`, the time complexity of this solution is `O(log N)`, which looks pretty good.

The idea behind this solution is standard: when we need to count how many number in the given range have a specif property (like sum of digits, xor or some other function of its digits), we place the digits one-by-one from the most significant to the least significant and keep track of 3 parameters: (number of digits already placed, is the prefix smaller than that of `N`, some problem-specific data).

Comment: @user269985 F#: `let g n = let rec f n = let arr = Array.zeroCreate<bigint> 16 in if n = 0I then arr, 0 else let d, r = bigint.DivRem(n, 10I) in let a, s = f d in begin for j = 0 to 15 do for i = 0 to 9 do arr.[j ^^^ i] <- arr.[j ^^^ i] + a.[j] done done; for i = 0 to int r - 1 do arr.[s ^^^ i] <- arr.[s ^^^ i] + 1I done; arr, s ^^^ int r end in n + 1I |> f |> fst |> Array.mapi (fun i c -> bigint i * c) |> Array.sum in g (bigint.Pow(10I, 100))`